# Simplify $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{((n+1)!)^{k+9}((k+9)(n))!}{((k+9)(n+1))!(n!)^{k+9}}|x|$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Where k is an unknown positive constant. I get to the point where
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(n+1)^{k+9}((k+9)(n))!}{((k+9)(n+1))!}|x|$ but I'm not sure how I can further simplify or if this is even correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have is correct, but you can go further: there’s still quite a bit of cancellation possible. Do you want to look for it yourself first?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews accidentally had x in the limit. Edited just before you commented.

Comment: $x$ is a constant?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes

Comment: @BrianM.Scott my thinking is I could cancel the ((k+9)(n))! on the top and bottom leaving me with (k+9)! on the bottom. But something seems wrong with that

Comment: It’s a bit messier than that, yes, and not quite so easy as I thought at first: I misread the parentheses. Let me write something up for you.

Comment: @That wouldn't be you misreading, I noticed I somehow made the same mistake twice putting it inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the crucial remaining cancellation:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(n+1)^{k+9}\big((k+9)n\big)!}{\big((k+9)(n+1)\big)!}&=\frac{(n+1)^{k+9}\big((k+9)n\big)!}{\big((k+9)n+(k+9)\big)!}\\\\
&=\frac{(n+1)^{k+9}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k+9}\big((k+9)n+i\big)}\\\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^{k+9}\frac{n+1}{(k+9)n+i}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The factorial in the numerator cancels with all but the largest $k+9$ factors of the factorial in the denominator.

From there getting the desired limit shouldn’t be too hard.